# Will a four ft tall American Beauty Bush continue growing if cut off at one ft,?

Tags: pruning

Pine forest , East TX, The National Forest Service clear cut everything smaller than 8 " diameter to make a fire break 100 yards wide adjacent to homes. NFS did this 4 years ago and 75 % of the new understory growth is American Beauty Bush up to 5 ' tall. The NFS is now repeating the clearing , they cut everything at about one foot height. I am wondering how fast the Bush will recover.

Answer (score 1):

Beauty Bush is very resilient. I've seen them taken down to 12" height, in the Spring. The shape might not be pleasing but they will right back quickly.